# Array shape valueError: fails (224,224,3) into (224,244,3). how to solve the problem?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

How to solve the failure of value input array `(224,224,3)` into `(224,244,3)` problem?

> `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,244,3)`

```
import numpy as np

images = np.zeros((3774,224,244,3))
img_no = 0
img = cv.imread(root + folder + "/" + file)
img = cv.resize(img, (224, 224))
images[img_no] = img
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_keras.py", line 34, in <module>
    load_data_to_a_file("dataset/test/", "test")
  File "E:\projects\final year project\My_work\resnet_implementation\testImageloader.py", line 23, in load_data_to_a_file
    images[img_no] = img
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,244,3)
```

Comment: The error message translates to: `images[img_no]` has size (224,244,3), but img after resize has size (224,224,3). They do not match so it can not be copied.

Comment: Can you try `images[img_no][:,:,:] = img[:,:,:]`

Comment: @SayandipDutta tried but not working

Comment: oh, I am so stupid @IcedLance you got the problem.. SOLVED. Thanks